# Does Magento have an Audit log for products?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, products, user

I am trying to figure out who created a product in my store and was wondering if there is an audit log that is a default feature within Magento. I've seen a few modules out there that do what I am looking for but I don't believe that will help with previous products.

Answer (score 1):

CE isn't that sophisticated. The best you can do is direct database access to the product table and hope that the created and modified columns have useful information.

Comment: Weak, i figured that was the case. I appreciate the response.